# how can I run "npm install && npm run dev on laravel 7?

Tags: laravel

i got this error when run command "npm install && npm run dev" on my project. 
I have tried to run the command "npm install" and i get the other error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhv5V.png)

Comment: run `npm install` press enter and when the process ends run `npm run dev`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to run:

```
npm install; npm run dev
```

The `&&` operation in CLI only works in `CMD` on Windows. In `Powershell` you have to use a `semicolon` instead.

Comment: `npm install && npm run dev`

Answer (score 2):

First try to update your nodejs version

```
npm install -g node
```

And then install cross-env globally

```
npm install --global cross-env
```

Finally install latest autoprefixer or 9.8.0 and run dev

```
npm install autoprefixer@9.8.0
npm install && run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is due to && operation in CLI, first of all, you have to install all dependencies using npm install and then you are allowed to run dev mode.

For real-time compiling you can use npm run watch instead of npm run dev.

Make sure you have installed node.js within your pc.

Comment: I installed node.js but it still failed